# Expand VLOOKUP range across multiple cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, find-replace

Maybe I went about this the wrong way initially, but this is what I have. I'm storing my students' grades in a Google Sheets document with a "Reports" sheet that pulls info from the other sheets.

`Reports!A1` is the student's name. Day 1 attendance is pulled from the Attendance sheet thusly:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Attendance!A1:Q10,2,false)`

Unfortunately, as you can see, I only planned for nine students. At the time, I had only ever had 5, so it seemed like a good number. Well, now I have eleven, and I need to expand the A1:Q10 range to at least A1:Q12. But no amount of Googling has given me a method to do this without manually editing 75 formulas. Surely there's some way, even if it involves exporting to some other format and re-importing, right?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: It's full of personal data, no way I could do that.

Comment: Apologies, what I should have said was... please share a copy of your spreadsheet excluding any private or confidential information. No one wants your actual school data, insert some dummy stuff instead. But we need to see the 75 formulas.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that afterwards. It was late. =) I got my answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd>
- and do:

  [image: 0]

and next time use 1 `ARRAYFORMULA` instead of 75 `VLOOKUP`s

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, Attendance!A:Q, COLUMN(B:Q), 0)))
```

Comment: Does the arrayformula assume that the 75 formulas are stacked in a column, or would it apply anywhere on a sheet?